# STMCubeIDE how to change the order of the includes

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

I have userspace STM32 MPU project. There are some toolchain defined include paths and some added by me. I want my one to be scanned before the "standard ones"

Is it archivable in this IDE?

Example - I want to move the uapi/linux one above the toolchain one:

[image]

Of course, I know how to add additional include paths, but those which come from the toolchain (or more generally from MPU SDK are not there):
[image]

Simply I want to swap the order of search (project include paths to be searched first):
[image]

for those who like gernerated command lines:

```
 arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/home/piotr/.eclipse/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.rcp.product_1.12.1_139061331_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/com.st.openstlinux.sdk.openstlinux_5.15_kirkstone_mp1_22_11_23_5.15.0.202301131307/tools/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi "../misc/ss.c" -std=gnu11 -g3 -D_GNU_SOURCE -c -I"/home/piotr/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.12.1/stm32MP157F-DK2-DEV/CA7/iproute/include" -I"/home/piotr/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.12.1/stm32MP157F-DK2-DEV/CA7/iproute/vdpa/include/uapi/linux" -Og -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"misc/ss.d" -MT"misc/ss.o" -o "misc/ss.o"
```

Comment: The view you show just sorts visually. Its order does not reflect the order of the includes in your sources. So please clarify: Which tool(s) should receive a changed order? The compiler, the indexer, ...? -- Did you look into the preferences of your project and did you try to change the order there? Assuming you did, please [edit] your question to clarify why this does not help you.

Comment: The include order of _headers_ should be as per the order appearing in the source starting at main.c. (Compile with -E to verify perhaps) Not to be confused with the order of linking .c files. Other than that, iirc Eclipse requires you to muck around with `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Compiler -> Includes` - Although the order of appearance there shouldn't matter (but never say never with Eclipse).

Comment: @Lundin It matters if I have the same name but with different defines. I want this one to be found first :). I want to have a particulat ***search order*** not an order of includes in my source file.  It is not related to linking at all.

Comment: @thebusybee no, it is not related to it.  I want to have a specific ***search order*** as I have some headers with the same names, but different content than the "standard" ones

Comment: Your question still lacks a statement for what tool you need to define the order. You need to differentiate between the IDE, its built-in tools like the indexer, and the compiler system.

Comment: @thebusybee the order really matters only for the compiler.

Comment: Yes, to compile, but you show us a view of the IDE. Please add this important statement to your question, do not hide it in a comment. If you want to show the order for the compiler, add the command line that calls the compiler.

Comment: @thebusybee the command line is generated by the IDE and it is in the order I do not want to be. I know how it works from the command line. I want to force CubeIDE to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prepend your include files before the system's include file. For this, you need to switch off the search of the system directories:

[image]

In consequence, you need to add all necessary system header files manually as you added the others header files. Set the order to your liking.

*Note: It seems like a brittle software design if you need to replace system definitions with your own.*

Comment: 1. It is MPU version and those options do not exist. 2. I do not want to disable the standard paths search, only change the order. 3. I know those options very well and I would not ask this question if it was so trivial.

Comment: You **urgently** need to add the command line to your question. If the system header files are not listed there, you **need** to apply the shown option.

Comment: Any you should have mentioned in your question that you know/tried that already, instead of letting us spend needless time to write an answer...

Comment: I wrote that trivial methods do not work. And it is one (BTW not correct as I do not want to stop searching there)